# What statistical property is absent in 2-sample hypothesis tests of 5 measurements?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, small-sample

Suppose we observe a random sample of five measurements: 10, 13, 15, 15, 17, from a normal distribution with unknown mean $\mu_1$ and unknown variance $\sigma_1^2$. A second random sample from another normal population with unknown mean $\mu_2$ and unknown variance $\sigma_2^2$ yields the measurements: 13, 7, 9, 15, 11.

If I test

a) $\sigma_1 > 1.0$ with a chi-squared test: $\chi^2 = \frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma_0^2}$

b) $\frac{\sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1^2}$ = 1 with an F-test

what desirable statistical property is absent in these tests?

I think that the answer is **power**, because the sample size is low.  However, I'm not absolutely sure.

Comment: Please tell us *how* you test, because the answers depend on that.

Comment: @whuber: I've updated my question to respond to your comment.

Comment: Thank you.  Because t-tests usually compare means, could you explain how you conceive of using a t-test to test a standard deviation and why the hypothesis appears to be unrelated to the second sample altogether?

Comment: Sorry - I meant to use the chi-squared test for part a)

Comment: Strange question(s): If you mean to test $H_0: \sigma_1 = 1$ vs $H_a: \sigma_1 > 1,$ then you can reject at 5% level, so it doesn't seem reasonable to complain about power. // If you mean to test $H_0: \sigma_1 = \sigma_2$ vs $H_a: \sigma_1 \ne \sigma_2$, then you can't reject and maybe you could complain about power. // Personally, I would complain about doing statistical analysis without any context of purpose, but that's probably not the answer they're looking for. Certainly, there's not enough data to test for normality, so you have only someone's allegation for that.

Comment: Maybe you're expected to mention there is no test on means. Welch 2-sample t test has P-value 0.1436, testing means equal against two-sided alternative.

Comment: I think that this discussion is WAY off tangent. I appreciate your time and responses, but you're not addressing the question that I asked. What is the statistical property that is absent? Is it power, as I guessed?